# Zoom out button when xy zoom is enbled

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can a zoom out button be implemented when xy zoom is enabled?

I would like the zoom to get 10% out every time the user presses the Zoom Out button

Comment: what do you expect this zoom to do? how does the zoom affect the chart?  smaller width and height?

Comment: Yes zoom out on both axis.

Comment: You can add an HTML button (positioned absolutely if needed) and then call [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes) with defined min/max.

Comment: Yes, I did that but how to compute the new extremes and for BOTH x and y axis